# HTTP POST .NET aspx.vb doesn't work using Class Library, works with Windows Forms Apps

Tags: vb.net, xmlhttprequest, http-post, httpwebrequest, get-request

I the code below works fine with using VS 2019 and selecting Windows Forms Applications from the project properties.  When I try to use the same code though in a "Class Library" for Web Forms, it doesn't work.

Target framework is .NET Framework 4.7.2 (i have to stay within .NET 4.0 for other references)
The host server requires me to login (username/password) via a pop-up when URL is entered on a web browser. This is why you see below request.Credentials being used. As far as I know, the host system is using TLS 1.2 as well.

The error shows when it hits
`Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream() 'Get the request stream.`

But the HTTP/S POST also doesn't work, but doesn't error out either.
Could it be a bug with built in IIS Express (Google Chrome)? I tried IE and Edge, same thing.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Public Class POST_ASN
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal  As Examples.System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    
    'End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim url As String = "https://myurl.somehost.com/invoke/HTTPConnector.Mailbox/post"
            Dim username As String = "user123"
            Dim password As String = "pass123"
            Dim networkCredential As New NetworkCredential(username, password)
            Dim postData As String = ""

            ' Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
    
            Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
            Request.Method = "POST"
            request.PreAuthenticate = True
            request.Credentials = networkCredential
            
            ' Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
            postData = "EDI data string here ASCII"

            Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
            request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream" ' Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length ' Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  

            'Get the request stream.  
            Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream() 
            'Write the data to the request stream.      
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)      
            ' Close the Stream object  
            dataStream.Close() 
            
            ' Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
            Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            
            ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
            Dim trackingID As String
            Using dataStream1 As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                'Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
                Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream1)
                ' Read the content.  
                Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
                trackingID = Mid(responseFromServer, 65, 10)
                ' Display the content.  
                MsgBox("Tracking ID: " & trackingID)
            End Using
            ' Clean up the response.  
            response.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I also read posts about setting ServicePointManager.SecuirtyProtocol, none of these worked, and i tried difference scenarios. According to MS, using .NET 4.7, TLS1.2 is already invoked.

```
'ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls 'Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

The purpose of all this was to migrate off my Excel VBA solution. This code below works fine, so if anyone knows how to take this and convert it to .NET Framework Class Library VB.aspx web page, please help.

```
'Create HTTP connection
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")            
xmlhttp.Open "POST", strURL, False, UploadUser, UploadPass 'Sync request
xmlhttp.Send sData
strValue = xmlhttp.responsetext
Set xmlhttp = Nothing
trackingID = Mid(strValue, 65, 10)
```

Comment: Can you share the error, if it's an exception the Exception type, stack trace, etc.

Comment: Does the code work in the class library when called from your Windows Forms app?

Comment: hi djv, I'll check this tomorrow on the actual exception error. i believe it was 426 (upgrade required), but its not the case since the host can support HTTP 1.1. misleading error i would think. Your other question. there is no class library on the properties options. once you select Windows app the IIS sever goes away and execution of the code is an .exe. I can double this tomorrow

Comment: Error: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
  Source=TEST1_Framework4
  StackTrace:
   at xxx_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in :\Users\xxxx\...aspx.vb:line 60

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond x.x.x.x:443

Comment: Ended up using C# to do the same thing (works), but I would still like to know how to do this in  .NET ASP using VB. This tells me that the VB part has a bug or something in the .NET framework.